# does this patent have to mentioned in

Tags: us8565243

In reference to the patent: [US8565243](https://www.google.com/patents/US8565243)

http://www.swirlds.com/ip/ they are using gossip protocol in 3 patents without mention of this patent.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't at all clear that the Swirds patents are related to US8565243. It is true that in one of the examples the word "Gossip" is included, but you would have to carefully examine whether the actual patented technology was related to US8565243. I'm not an expert in this field so I'll have to defer on that evaluation. However, this is one of those cases where the possible prior art to a US patent is another US patent. My experience is that the USPTO is pretty good about finding prior art within their own records. I'd have to surmise that the patent examiner decided that US8565243 is not prior art to Swirds' patents.

In any case, the assignee for US8565243 is Red Hat which is a substantial organization. I would assume they would demand a license if they thought that Swirds was infringing on their IP.